# В чём может быть проблема при работе с namespace?

Tags: php, phpunit

Не понимаю ошибку. Как он его не находит если я всё указал? 
Перехожу с java на php и может не замечаю тупую ошибку но из-за непривычки.

Использую PHPUnit.

1-й вариант:

```
<?php namespace ClassTester;

use PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase;
use data\User;
use model\DBHandler;  // Указал !!! 

class ClassTester extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

public function testExist(){
    $handler = new DBHandler();
    $exist = $handler->exist(new User(******", "*****", "*****", "*******"));
    if($exist){
        echo "User exist in database! ";
    }elseif(!$exist){
        echo "<pre>";
        echo "You need to register this user it is not exist! ";
        echo "</pre>";
    }
}
```

2-й вариант:

```
<?php 

use data\User;

class ClassTester extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

public function testExist(){
    $handler = new\model\DBHandler();
    $exist = $handler->exist(new User(******", "*****", "*****", "*******"));
    if($exist){
        echo "User exist in database! ";
    }elseif(!$exist){
        echo "<pre>";
        echo "You need to register this user it is not exist! ";
        echo "</pre>";
    }
}
```

Ошибка которую получаю в обоих случаях:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'model\DBHandler' not found in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/PHPUnitP/projectfiles/tests/classtester/ClassTester.php:8

Comment: Не хватает инклуда с этим классом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Неймспейсы в PHP глобализуют идентификаторы. Т.е.

```
namespace ClassTester;
class ClassTester {
```

объявляет класс с именем `ClassTester\ClassTester`. Объявление

```
namespace ClassTester1;
class ClassTester {
```

объявит совершенно другой класс.

Оператор `use` позволяет указать какой именно идентификатор мы используем и не писать его полное имя.

При этом, если мы используем какой-то идентификатор, объявленный в другом файле, то мы должны этот файл подключить к нашему при помощи операторов `inclide/require` (_once) (явно или опосредовано)

Comment: Непонятная система в ПХП для импорта кода жесть какаято зачем так запутывать.. 
В Java import или static Import и всё .. СПС за ответ помогли!

Comment: @Mekudad Изначально был инклуд. И все жили. А потом выяснилось, что разные разработчики имеют тенденцию называть свои классы одними и теми же именами. И возник коллапс. Тогда придумали неймспейсы, чтобы этот коллапс разрулить.